# How do I apply a diff patch on Windows?

Tags: windows, diff, gnu, patch

There are plenty of programs out there that can create a diff patch, but I'm having a heck of a time trying to apply one. I'm trying to distribute a patch, and I got a question from a user about how to apply it. So I tried to figure it out on my own and found out that I have no clue, and most of the tools I can find are command-line. (I can handle a command line, but a lot of people would be lost without a nice, friendly GUI. So those are no good for this purpose.)

I tried using TortoiseSVN. I have the patch I'd like to apply. I right-click on the patch, and there's an option under the TortoiseSVN submenu that says "Apply patch." All it does is pull up an empty window.

So I tried hitting Open. It has two options: merge and apply unified diff. (The patch is in unified diff format, luckily.) But the apply option just plain doesn't work: It asks for the patch and a folder. Somehow it forgot to ask for the *file to apply the patch to!* So TortoiseSVN just plain doesn't work. Is there a Windows GUI-based utility that will take a patch and a file and apply it properly?

EDIT: Looking at the replies so far, it seems that Tortoise will only do it right if it's a file that's already versioned. That's not the case here. I need to be able to apply a patch to a file that did not come out of an SVN repository. I just tried using Tortoise, because I happen to know that SVN uses diffs and has to know how to both create them and apply them.

Comment: WinMerge answer sounded good but only explains how to make a patch, not how to apply one.  TortoiseHG has a great way to apply patches, but only to files that are in an hg repo, as far as  I know.  If the external SVN TortoiseDiff can't do it, I wonder if any  GUI tool can.

Comment: Wow, you are right the short answer is still no - at least in WinMerge. Feature request on WinMerge here https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=695741&group_id=13216&atid=363216

Comment: It didn't "forget" to ask for the file to apply the patch to, the filename is contained inside the patchfile.

Answer (score 33):

**Apply Patch**

## With TortoiseMerge:

1. Find and open an existing SVN repo directory
2. Create a new directory named "merges", if it does not exist already
3. Copy the file onto which you want to apply the .patch file
4. **ADD and COMMIT to the svn repository before you continue to the next step**
5. Right click on merges and choose **Apply patch...**
6. Double click the file from list
7. The patched file with diff is displayed on the right pane
8. Click on that pane and hit **Save** or export with **File->Save As...**

Alternative screeny if you Open from TortoiseMerge.  In the screeny below, directory refers to the "merges" directory mentioned at step 2 above:
[image: Screeny]

Screenshot of WinMerge GUI:
[image: Screeny]

Comment: @WarrenP : yes it does explain how to apply the patch using TortoiseMerge

Comment: My comment made sense before edits, and no longer makes sense after edits.  Are you confused yet?  The edit timestamp above (mar 24, '11) appears to be incorrect, since the OP has edited his answer again since October 2011. I think the timestamp on my comment is wrong too.

Comment: @SheriffMd Don't you receive the error "D:\Folder is not a working copy" ?

Comment: @SheriffMd I also get the message "folder ... is not a working copy" - so, how is it possible to use tortoise merge to apply a patch to non-versioned file?

Comment: @onmyway133, I've rephrased the steps.  Refer Step 2 and Step 4.  You will not receive the "not a working copy" error message.

Answer (score 21):

I made [pure Python tool](https://github.com/techtonik/python-patch/blob/master/patch.py) just for that. It has predictable cross-platform behavior. Although it doesn't create new files (at the time of writing this) and lacks a GUI, it can be used as a library to create graphic tool.

**UPDATE**: It should be more convenient to use it if you have Python installed.

```
pip install patch
python -m patch
```

Comment: I use this a lot. Thanks @techtonik. Any news on getting it working with Python3?

Comment: Run pip install patch with adminstration rights to be sure it works.

Comment: @Vertexwahn is it on Linux?

Comment: Python runs everywhere - I tested it with Windows 10

Comment: Worked on Windows 10 when git patch wouldn't work. Thank you!

Comment: There are many issues in my 2012 pet `python-patch` project and I realize that I haven't got enough free `braincells*time*money` resources to test it on latest Python versions and at least address all requests. Sorry about that. The economics suxx.

Comment: Just worked on Win 10 with Python 2.7.  Unified diff produced by TortoiseGit was a source. To choose destination I had simply run the utility from directory the target file was located in.

Answer (score 21):

The patch.exe utility from the Git installation works on Windows 10.

Install [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) then use the `"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\patch.exe"` command to apply a patch.

If any error message like a `Hunk #1 FAILED at 1 (different line endings).` had been got on the output during applying a patch, try to add the `-l` (that is a shortcut for the `--ignore-whitespace`) or the `--binary` switches to the command line.

Comment: This question is mostly about a GUI tool for casual users who are not familiar with the typical command-line tools. Your answer would be more useful if you at least provided some full sample commands as example.

Comment: Works with composer in Windows 10.

Answer (score 18):

[TortoiseMerge](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/TortoiseMerge.html) is a separate utility that comes bundled with TortoiseSVN.

It can also be can be downloaded separately in the [TortoiseDiff.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/Tools/) archive. This will allow you to apply unified diffs to non-versioned files.

Comment: AFAIK this cannot apply patch on a non-versioned file.

Comment: I didn't have a problem applying it to a non-versioned file.

Comment: others kinda want to :S.

Comment: Version 1.8.7 gives an error about the dest not being versioned.

Comment: Cannot appy to a non versioned working copy

Answer (score 16):

I know you said you would prefer a GUI, but the commandline tools will do the work nicely. See [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) for a port of unix tools to Windows. You'd need the patch command, obviously ;-)

You might run into a problem with the line termination, though. The GnuWin port will assume that the patchfile has DOS style line termination (CR/LF). Try to open the patchfile in a reasonably smart editor and it will convert it for you.

Comment: Well put. Wouldn't have been able to figure out the line termination problem without this comment.

Comment: Another way to deal with the line endings is to add the "--binary" option to the command line.

Comment: This was what got me on the right track. However, running Windows 7 or newer you need to update the manifest of patch.exe to avoid having the UAC pop-up each time. See this page for a how-to: http://math.nist.gov/oommf/software-patchsets/patch_on_Windows7.html

Comment: Even with the UAC fixes, the GnuWin version of patch messes up file security settings. The build shipped with git doesn't suffer from either issue.

Answer (score 7):

In TortoiseSVN, patch applying does work. You need to apply the patch to the same directory as it was *created from*. It is always important to keep this in mind. So here's how you do it in TortoiseSVN:

Right click on the folder you want to apply the patch to. It will present a dialog asking for the location of the patch file. Select the file and this should open up a little file list window that lists the changed files, and clicking each item should open a diff window that shows what the patch is about to do to that file.

Good luck.

Comment: That doesn't help. The destination files didn't come out of an SVN archive.  (See the edit to the original post.)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [this](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) Win32 native port of the patch utility.

It comes along with a bigger selection of other utilities and in contrast to Cygwin and similar it does not need any DLLs or similar. Just pick your tiny executable of choice and store it wherever you want.

Simple usage:

```
patch.exe -i <patchfile>
```

Get more help:

```
patch.exe --help
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with this on Windows 7: it opens a new CMD window and prompts for administrative privileges when I attempt to run `patch.exe`.

Comment: The patch executable can also be found in the Git for Windows bundle.

Comment: If you are running into issues running patch.exe, you can rename it to anything that does not include `patch`. Windows considers all exes with the word `patch` to be suspect.

Answer (score 3):

I am already using BeyondCompare (commercial) for diffs and merges, and this tool also [has the capability](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_patch) to create, view and apply patches.

Answer (score 3):

I use MSYS2 from http://www.msys2.org/

It provides many utilities like `patch`, `which`, `git`, `tree`, and many more.

After installing MSYS2 simply run the package manager to install `patch`:

```
pacman -S patch
```

Comment: This is just a convoluted way to install a command-line tool. I suspect you only read the question title and not the question itself. :)

Answer (score 2):

> EDIT: Looking at the replies so far, it seems that Tortoise will only do it right if it's a file that's already versioned. That's not the case here. I need to be able to apply a patch to a file that did not come out of an SVN repository. I just tried using Tortoise because I happen to know that SVN uses diffs and has to know how to both create them and apply them.

You can install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/), then use the command-line *patch* tool to apply the patch. See also [this Unix man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch), which applies to *patch*.

Comment: Yeah, I could.  I've got Cygwin, in fact.  I could probably make your solution work, too.  I'm not gonna put my users through that, though.  You have any idea how many Windows users these days don't even know what a command line is? :P

Answer (score 2):

It appears that TortoiseSVN (TortoiseMerge) [requires the line `Index: foobar.py`](http://groups.google.com/group/tortoisesvn/msg/54686dcdd3126af0) in the diff/patch file. This is what I needed to do to make a non-TortoiseSVN patch file work with TortoiseSVN's right-click *Apply Patch* command.

Before:

```
--- foobar.py.org   Sat May 08 16:00:56 2010
+++ foobar.py   Sat May 08 15:47:48 2010
```

After:

```
Index: foobar.py
===================================================================
--- foobar.py
+++ foobar.py   (working copy)
```

Or if you know the specific revision your contributor was working from:

```
Index: foobar.py
===================================================================
--- foobar.py   (revision 1157)
+++ foobar.py   (working copy)
```

Answer (score 1):

The patch tells it what file to apply to. The header should be something like (view it in Notepad or your fav text editor):

```
--- Folder/old_file
+++ Folder/new_file
```

In the case of a Subversion patch, you'd have revision numbers as well (since the file names are the same).

[GNU patch](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/patch/) will let you *override* those names, but I don't know of any GUI tools to do the same. I'd check with the various diff programs - though, it does not appear WinMerge supports applying patches.

Comment: No, there's nothing like that at the top of my patch. Are you saying that the filename and path has to be included in the diff itself? Who thought that up? What are you supposed to do if you want to distribute a diff to someone who might have things installed in other folders?!?

Comment: The top of the patch starts out like this:  --- / +++ / @@ -6,12 +6,12 @@  No filenames or anything.  How is a built-in path supposed to work? What if I created the patch on XP and someone's trying to use it on Vista (or vice-versa) and the path to the Documents folder is different?

Comment: The filenames are relative to the root directory of the repository, so XP/Vista folder structure differences don't matter. And the reason for having filenames in the patch is that most patches affect multiple files.

Comment: I see.  OK, that makes more sense.  Thanks for clearing that up, David!

Comment: @MasonWheeler: A patchfile requires the filename lines.  If your file doesn't have that, it's not a patchfile (it may have been created by diff -- not all combinations of command-line options to diff will create patchfiles)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial), this is done via "import". So at the command line, the `hg import` command, or (you may find the `--no-commit` option useful), or "Repository" => "Import..." in Hg Workbench.

Note that these will commit the changes by default; you can avoid this using  `hg import --no-commit` option if using the command-line, or if you used Hg Workbench, you might find it useful to issue `hg rollback` after the merge.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I was wondering how to avoid the commit.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse should be able to do it, go to TeamSynchronize perspective and then into Project->Apply patch

Answer (score 1):

For Java projects, I have used [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) to apply patch files. If the Java code you are patching is not already a NetBeans project, create a project for it. To create a new project:

- Select menu *File* -> *New Project*
- In the resulting dialog, make it a *Java Application project*. Give it a name in the dialog, and click <kbd>Finish</kbd>.
- Right-click the name of your project, and select Properties from the context menu
- In the resulting dialog, select *Sources*, and add a *Source Folder*. Browse to your Java source.

Now that you have a project, apply the patch:

- Highlight your project to select it
- From the main menu, select menu *Tools* -> *Apply Diff Patch*
- In the resulting dialog, browse to your patch file, select it, and press the Patch button.

That's it. Your patch should be applied, and you should see a diff window showing the changes.

Answer (score 1):

## Using git Diff or linux patch to apply a patch on windows using git diff

Patches created anywhere on linux, MacOS or else, using the GNU patch command or git diff can be all applied on windows using git apply.

### Create the patch

For instance to create the patch from 2 directories in which 1 or more files have been changed:

`diff -Naru original_dir modified_dir > 0001-path-file.patch`

- "-N" treat absent files as empty, necessary to only consider modified content
- "-a" treat all files as text, not compulsory, needs removed if dealing - with binary patches.
- "-r" recursive for directories traversal
- "-u" adds 3 lines of context by default around all diffs

OR using git diff

`git diff original_dir modified_dir > 0001-path-file.patch`

Then copy the .patch file on the windows environment as well as the original_dir directory that contains the original unchanged files.

### Apply with git diff:

- Pre-requisite: Install git, i.e. from https://git-scm.com/downloads

1 Copy the patch file in the parent directory

2 cd into the original directory

3 Apply the patch using git apply

```
copy 0001-path-file.patch ..\original_dir\
cd original_dir
git apply < 0001-path-file.patch
```

Answer (score 0):

When applying patches using TortoiseSVN, I typically save the path in the root of the checked out repository.  You should then be able to right click on the patch, go to the TortoiseSVN menu, and click ApplyPatch.  ApplyPatch should automatically figure out which level in the directory hierarchy the patch was created.

I have, however, had issues in the past with applying patches that contain new files, or which involve renames to files.  Whatever algorithm Tortoise uses for this doesn't seem to handle those scenarios very well.  Unicode can give you similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting "Not a working copy" error message then try selecting a directory from TortoiseMerge dialog box which is a working directory of SVN.

Answer (score 0):

A [BusyBox](ftp://ftp.tigress.co.uk/public/gpl/6.0.0/busybox/) port for Windows has both a diff and patch command, but they only support unified format.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
patch -p0 < path-file.patch
```

remember execute this command only from the folder location where you created the patch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **git install on Windows** and you want to **apply a patch for a git repository**, you can simply do **from a Windows Power Shell**:

```
git apply ..\0001-your-patch.patch
```

Answer (score 0):

in response to the query earlier about patch and Python 3, I got the error
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

The solution for me was to change the source, in the _normalize_filenames function:

```
-        debug("    target = " + p.target)
-        debug("    source = " + p.source)
+        debug("    target = ", p.target)
+        debug("    source = ", p.source)
```

then patch worked fine for me (Python 3, Windows 10)