# Drupal how to override someone else's function

Tags: drupal

I downloaded someone's Drupal module (non core) I changed 1 function in there. I want my changes to not be over written by future module updates however still able to enjoy new updates.

How do you do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use hooks, but if there are no other solutions ...

Simplest solution : create a diff, apply a patch manually after module's automatic update.

http://jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html

Or You could edit try to edit Your module's info file, overriding the configuration of the version & the datestamp of Your module, to avoid automatic updates.

Comment: thanks guys! how do you create and apply a patch on windows system?

Comment: It's an another question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517257/how-do-i-apply-a-diff-patch-on-windows :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally if you have changed something, this means **you are no longer having the version that can be maintained by the original developer** (unless he applies the same change in his/her module).

But your options are:

1. **making original module more flexible / expanding it:** If you are familiar with the **concept of Drupal's hooks**, you can use them to build your own module and that way modify the way this module behaves. If it has no hooks in the feature you need, you can add them and ask author to merge the changes so when someone installs your module, it seamlessly integrates with his/her module.
2. **using version control system:** Alternatively you can check the updates in a different way, not from Drupal itself. You can **use Git to download that module** (drupal.org modules directory provides you with Git access), and use it to **merge new versions to your code** - then what you need is to be more familiar with Git versioning system.

Answer (score 1):

If your changed function fix a bug or something else, is better to create a path and propose your modification to the maintainer.

Otherwise, if you just modify the function to help your project, you should also create a patch and apply it after every update of your module.

Another solution, but less elegant, its to clone the module and create your own with the modified function (like this, your module can be out of updates).