# Is it possible to apply SVN patch to plain (non-svn) folder?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

For some reason, (please dont ask me why!), I wonder something.

Suppose that;

- I have created a patch file for some changes on my project (which is a SVN folder).
- I reverted any changes on this folder and exported SVN revisioned files.
- I try to apply this patch on this exported files folder which is obviously not an SVN folder and utility gives this error, too. ("* is not a working copy")

So, is it possible to apply a patch to a non-SVN folder with same file/folder structure etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the Unix `patch` command. If using SVN 1.8 or later, you may want to use the [`--patch-compatible`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.patch_compatible) switch when generating the patch.

Comment: You have numerous options on Windows, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517257/how-do-i-apply-a-diff-patch-on-windows).